# Populate Drop Down List On Google Form Via Google Script

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying to populate a form's drop down list on a google form via a google sheet. I've been looking at the following [website](http://wafflebytes.blogspot.ca/2016/10/google-script-create-drop-down-list.html) and it's been walking me through the process. The issue is that I can't figure out the ID of the drop down list via the "inspect element" feature. I'm using Safari on a Mac. Here's what I see when I highlight the element:

[image]

Any idea what the ID would be?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Just in case any one runs into the same issue, the value you're looking for is called `data-observe-id`. Here's an image of what it looks like:

[image]